# Plot a 3-D Triangle in the cartesian coordinate system with vertices A(6,-1,2), B(-2,3,-4), C(-3,1,5) in matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d

I have already managed to plot the 3-D Triangle using Matlab by calling the fill3 function.
This is what i used

```
         **declare and initialize variables**
         X=[6,-1,2];Y=[-2,3,-4],Z=[-3,1,5], C=[00001];

         **Call fill3 function so that all vertices are mapped**
           fill3=(X,Y,Z,C)
```

However, i have failed to indicate the vertices A,B,C on the actual 3D figure. Find below the image;
[image: 3-D TRIANGLE]

How do i indicate the vertices ABC on the 3D-Triangle?

Comment: Notice that the coordinates in your code don’t match the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this line below your code

```matlab
text(X,Y,Z,['A';'B';'C'],'fontsize',18); % change font size at will
```

And this is the result

[image]

If you don't want the labels to overlap the triangle, you can modify the coordinates of the labels. For instance, define some suitably modified coordinates `X1`, `Y1` and `Z1` and replace the above line with

```matlab
text(X1,Y1,Z1,['A';'B';'C'],'fontsize',18);
```